# pandas/dataframe/datetimes how to extract age from brth_dt column

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I got a column “brth_dt” and its type was datetime64[ns],how to extract people's age from it?I searched a lot,but find no answer in the "pandas: powerful Python data analysis toolkit Release 0.19.2"

`df['brth_dt'].head()`

```
cst_id  
1       1976-09-23
2       1967-01-09
3       1990-08-04
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract the birth date from today and divide the days by 365

```
df['age'] = (pd.datetime.today() - df['brth_dt']).dt.days/365
```

or multiply by `0.00273973` based on google

```
df['age'] = (pd.datetime.today() - df['brth_dt']).dt.days*0.00273973
```

Output :

```
    brth_dt        age
0 1976-09-23  40.906909
1 1967-01-09  50.619251
2 1990-08-04  27.035656
```

If you want to just subtract the year you can also do

```
df['age'] = (pd.datetime.today().year - df['brth_dt'].dt.year)
```

Output:

```
     brth_dt  age
0 1976-09-23   41
1 1967-01-09   50
2 1990-08-04   27
```

Comment: works well,tks.btw,I want to use iloc to extract data,like df.iloc[:,2:3],but how to confirm the number for column df['age']?

Comment: Do you mean getting the index of the column age?

Comment: Use `get_loc` i.e `df.columns.get_loc('age')`, do accept the answer if it was helpful and upvote too :)

Comment: have accepted..how to change a column's index,like move it to the last column

Comment: You have to do manually based on your needs sir. like `df = df[['age','brth_dt']]`. Do vote